# Dead circuit / outlets

Tags: wiring, receptacle

I have a handful of electrical outlets that went dead. I have a Kolsol F02 wire locator that I used to identify the circuit breaker they are on, and it seems like I have connectivity from the breaker to the each wire/screw on (assumed) first outlet, from the first to the last outlet, and from there back to the breaker. I also verified the circuit breaker passes all 240v when on.

They seem to be the only thing on this circuit, since I can't find anything else that isn't working with the breaker turned off.

So, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Are these outlets wired using side-screws or backstabs?

Comment: Do you have a GFCI in one outlet that might be controlling the others?

Comment: Did you check both hot and neutral wires?

Comment: They are using side-screws, and I tested the 2 hot and 2 neutral wires at the beginning and end outlets. I've checked all the (few) GFCI in the house, they are all functional.

Comment: This is a 120V circuit, right?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel OP said "I verified the circuit breaker passess all _240v_ when on", so it's probably not 120v. :)

Comment: It's 120v at the outlet, 240 across the breaker. *shrug* I'm not even a novice at this stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

Continuity is NOT a good test as it only verifies a circuit, not how much the wire will carry, ie, a braided wire with only a few strands will test continuous but not carry a designed load.  Have you tried disconnecting each appliance at the its personal connection and taking a reading there to verify the voltage there as opposed to the fuse box ?? If the 240 is present then each appliance individually should be working.  If not is there a reset button, (thinking of a possible surge kicking off the resets but power showing oK after the surge)(we had a lightning hit transformer blow and it kicked every reset and switch in the house).  Get a good set of clamps so that YOU are not holding your test leads in place, remember, circuit brkr OFF,  disconnect or  clamp, close brkr, test reading, check reset, If ALL good  then on to next appliance.

Answer (score 1):

When I went to turn on the breaker today and take the measurements suggested, I had my daughter do it and she didn't push hard enough and it popped back halfway, so she pushed it over again. I checked the voltage again and it was zero! Anyway, I ended up playing with it a bit, forcing it off, then turned it back on and got 240v. Then I decided to try the outlets and they were working.

I assume my kids overloaded it and it tripped without moving the handle. I can't 100% say that in my prior testing I turned it off and back on. Thanks for the time investigating.